# Don't we have to prove that A(i,j) = <b(i),b(j)>?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, machine-learning, positive-definite

Hope you're doing good!

Well I have a problem. The thing is when wanting to prove that a matrix A is a symmetric positive definite matrix then all you have to do is prove that A is symmetric and that $\forall \boldsymbol{x} \in V \backslash\{\mathbf{0}\}: \boldsymbol{x}^{\top} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}>0$.
But assuming the following:

Consider an $n$ -dimensional vector space $V$ with an inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ :
$V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (see Definition 3.3 ) and an ordered basis $B=\left(b_{1}, \ldots, b_{n}\right)$ of
$V$. Recall from Section 2.6 .1 that any vectors $x, y \in V$ can be written as linear combinations of the basis vectors so that $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \psi_{i} b_{i} \in V$ and $\boldsymbol{y}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{j} \boldsymbol{b}_{j} \in V$ for suitable $\psi_{i}, \lambda_{j} \in \mathbb{R}$. Due to the bilinearity of the
inner product, it holds for all $x, y \in V$ that
$$
\langle\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \psi_{i} \boldsymbol{b}_{i}, \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{j} \boldsymbol{b}_{j}\right\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \psi_{i}\left\langle\boldsymbol{b}_{i}, \boldsymbol{b}_{j}\right\rangle \lambda_{j}=\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}^{\top} \boldsymbol{A} \hat{\boldsymbol{y}}
$$

Then why don't we have to prove that $A_{i j}:=\left\langle\boldsymbol{b}_{i}, \boldsymbol{b}_{j}\right\rangle$ to know if the matrix represented an inner product of V?

Example:

$$
\boldsymbol{A}_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
9 & 6 \\
6 & 5
\end{array}\right]
$$
$A_{1}$ is positive definite because it is symmetric and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{x}^{\top} \boldsymbol{A}_{1} \boldsymbol{x} &=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
x_{1} & x_{2}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
9 & 6 \\
6 & 5
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
x_{1} \\
x_{2}
\end{array}\right] \\
&=9 x_{1}^{2}+12 x_{1} x_{2}+5 x_{2}^{2}=\left(3 x_{1}+2 x_{2}\right)^{2}+x_{2}^{2}>0
\end{aligned}
$$
Why don't we have to prove that Aij = ⟨bi,bj⟩?

Thanks in advanced for your reponses.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by "assuming the following... ": what are $b_j$ and what are $\psi_i,\lambda_j$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I'm going to add everything now. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: You ask, "why do we have to prove that $A_{ij}=\langle b_i,b_j\rangle$?" and then you ask, "why don't we have to prove that $A_{ij}=\langle b_i,b_j\rangle$?" so which is it?

Comment: My bad the question is why don't we have to do it. Just fixed it.

Comment: As you wrote in your 1st paragraph, all you have to do is see that $A$ is symmetric and that $x^tAx>0$ for all non-zero $x$.